# Custom field type XSL in SP2010

Tags: xslt, custom-field-types, caml-renderpattern

Has anybody upgraded an old custom field type to use the new XSL transform in SharePoint 2010? I have a multi-column field type, and want the Display pattern to render the 2nd "column", which contains a hyperlink. My CAML render pattern looks like:

```
<RenderPattern Name="DisplayPattern">
   <Switch>
      <Expr>
         <Column />
      </Expr>
      <Case Value="" />
      <Default>
         <HTML><![CDATA[<a href=']]></HTML>
         <Column SubColumnNumber="1" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
         <HTML><![CDATA['>]]></HTML>
         <Column SubColumnNumber="1" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
         <HTML><![CDATA[</a>]]></HTML>
      </Default>
   </Switch>
</RenderPattern>
```

In WSS 3.0, this would render the 2nd column in the field as a hyperlink in the LVWP, which is what I want. In SharePoint 2010, I tried adding TRUE to my field type definition, but that ends up rendering the actual anchor tag, as opposed to a clickable hyperlink:

```
<a href="http://www.something.com">www.something.com</a>
```

So then I tried creating a XSL transform, since that is supposed to be the new and improved way of doing this. Unfortunately, I can't get that to work either. I am getting the same thing I got using the RenderPattern. I'm no XSL expert, so can anyone confirm (or deny) that the following looks legitimate (or suggest a better way to do it)?

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">

  <xsl:template match="FieldRef[@FieldType='DataLinkUrl']" mode="Note_body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="url">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name],';#'),';#'),';#')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <a href="{$url}"><xsl:value-of select="$url"/></a>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.silver-it.com/node/66) will help you to understand how mode attribute value is calculated.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful in confirming what I already had for the "mode" attribute. In case anyone is interested in the future, I ended up using the ddwrt:HtmlDecode function to get my URL properly decoded:

<xsl:variable name="link">
          <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring-after(ddwrt:HtmlDecode($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]),',')" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <a href="{substring-before(substring-after($link,'href=&quot;'),', ')}">Link</a>